# Getting the login status of users of my site and view the number of users with there name form database using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need help in "How to get the login status of users of my site and view the number of users with there name form database using php or Jquery...."
OR 
Simply getting the numbers of users online on my website....

Comment: What attempts did you make so far that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of phpAcademy? Alex Garret has made a number of FREE video courses that will help you.

Link: http://phpAcademy.org

For your question, especially look at the [Registration and Login tutorial](https://phpacademy.org/course/register-login)